# array undefined after pushing to object

Tags: javascript

I'm pushing an object into an array of objects. One of the properties of the object (which is an array) is showing up as undefined, after the object is pushed to the array. If you look at my code below, where it says, "WHY IS THIS SHOWING IN CONSOLE?" - it doesn't make sense because if the array is undefined, it should have been undefined in both of the previous two checks (where it says "THIS IS NOT SHOWING IN CONSOLE."). This is driving me crazy. SOS. Please help.

```
            var pathCopy = unit.path; // THIS IS AN ARRAY AND IT IS NOT EMPY
            var directionCopy = unit.direction;

            if (pathCopy.length < 1) {
                console.log('THIS IS NOT SHOWING IN CONSOLE');
            }
            var object = {
                'type': 'move',
                'time': gameTime,
                'name': unit.name,
                'vector': pathCopy,
                'direction': directionCopy

            };

            currentGameEvents.push(object);

            if (object.vector.length < 1) {
                console.log('THIS IS NOT SHOWING IN CONSOLE');

            }

            for (var i = 0; i < currentGameEvents.length; i++) {
                if (currentGameEvents[i].vector.length < 1) {
                    console.log('WHY IS THIS SHOWING IN CONSOLE??');
                }

            }
```

Comment: Any chance you have other objects in `currentGameEvents` that have an empty `vector` array? You should probably log out some other details in your loop, eg `console.log(i, currentGameEvents[i].name)`

Comment: If you want to copy an array (`pathCopy`, `directionCopy`), use `.slice()` at the end as well. Otherwise the reference is kept.

Comment: I created a basic example and it didn't do what you claim. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure how or why, but your example works, if I insert the undefined variables (i.e. I replaced `unit.path` with `[345,34623,52]` or something that is an array literal).

The only difference to that is, that you actually assign the *reference* to that array, instead of declaring a *new* array.

```
var pathCopy = unit.path; // pathCopy and unit.path are the SAME array
```

```
var pathCopy = [345,346,345]; // pathCopy is a completely NEW array
```

To fix this, try something like

```
var pathCopy = unit.path.slice(); // pathCopy is a completely NEW array that contains the same values as unit.path
```

whenever you want to *copy* an *array*; add `.slice()` at the end!

Again, this is deducing from the only difference between your code and what I tried, and this is *probably* the reason, why your code doesn’t work.

---

Another assumption is that `currentGameEvents` is an `Array`. Your code wouldn’t work at all, otherwise. I’m mentioning this because the title states that you were trying to `push` *to* an object, which isn’t possible.

Comment: There's nothing in OP's code to suggest the referenced array is being changed between the 2nd and 3rd console logs

Comment: @Phil Who knows? He didn’t mention what the missing values were, as well, so maybe that part of his code is missing, too.

Comment: You don't need to assume it's an array, it's right there in OP's question ~ *"I'm pushing an object into an array of objects"*

Comment: It was an array, but using slice() did solve the problem. Oddly, slice() was the first thing I tried but it didn't work ... I think I may have forgotten to clear my browser cache when I tested it the first time. But slice() was necessary because the array was being changed after it had been put into the object. So I needed a new array instead of a reference. Thanks!